# Java Service on Azure tomcat failing with

Tags: java, azure

We created a APP Service on Azure on Tomcat 9.9 ( using Java 8) and deployed  war file using eclipse. The project ( war) is a rest api using jax-rs and has a simple  get method to retrieve data from oracle database and return a json output.

The rest call is failing with javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/UCPPool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Thanks.

```
We have done configured context.xml under META-INF folder and also have added entry to web. xml and also uploaded jdbc jar to Azure tomcat as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-java#data-sources

 Can someone please provide some pointers how to resolve the error.
```

Comment: Context.xml

 <Resource
     name="jdbc/UCPPool"
     auth="Container"
     type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:1521:XXXX"
     username="xxx"
     password="xxx"
     connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true"
     accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
     maxTotal="25"
     maxIdle="10"
     maxWaitMillis="10000"
     />  
    </Context>

Comment: Web.xml 

  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/EDEVLMDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>
   </web-app>

Comment: Please don't try to explain your question in comments on your question.  As you can see, comments don't support proper formatting.  Instead, [edit] your question to add any information that is required to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the application locally and then you can try to deploy it on Azure? 
Also, check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/create%2C-deploy%2C-and-run-java-apps-connecting-to-atp-on-azure) that connects to ATP for a reference.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. The application is working fine on my local machine.  thanks for the blog, I followed all steps as per blog except the credentials piece  as i  am using "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"  but its failing with same error.